# <select> required not working

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I'am using this code along with php code for a select and used required class to make it mandatory but it is not working. Does anyone can help me.I have included this html section along with php code.

```
 <select name="category" required="required" class="form-control">
        <option value=" ">--Select Category--</option>
        <option value="asd">asd</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Try to remove space value in your select category option

Comment: Just try my answer below :) and see if it works

Comment: @JosanIracheta using chromium browser(linux OS)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try to remove space value in your select category option

```
<select name="category" required="required" class="form-control">
    <option value="">--Select Category--</option>
    <option value="asd">asd</option>
</select> code here
```

Answer (score 15):

First of all, replace

```
 <option value=" ">--Select Category--</option>
```

with

```
 <option value="">--Select Category--</option>
```

And then, as [w3c](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-required-attribute) says, ... "The required attribute is a boolean attribute. When specified, the element is required."

```
 <select name="category" required class="form-control">
     <option value="">--Select Category--</option>
     <option value="asd">asd</option>
 </select>
```

Also [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp) you can find same example.

And [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_required) you can try the code.

Required is working. The fact is that " " is a value and "" is not.

Comment: Write `required="required"` is the same thing than to write `required` so i don't think it will resolve his problem.

Comment: If you do not trust to me, trust w3c or w3cschool. The above is just their, not mine. ^_^

Comment: I can trust you, but [I don't](http://php.net/manual/en/function.delete.php) [trust W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_delete.asp)

Comment: I believe you, and I believe w3c, but what is not written on the page that you shared, is the fact that a Boolean attribute can be written `attribute` or `attribute="attribute"`

Comment: if you did not set value to option, that doesnt work. like : <option selected disabled>Choose Category</option> You should add value="" to make required validation work

Answer (score 2):

You have to add required and value attributes

```
<select required="true" name="unit">
<option disabled selected value="">-- Select One --</option>
<option>Square Feet</option>
<option>Square Yards</option>
<option>Square Meters</option>
<option>Marla</option>
<option>Kanal</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `required` attribute on the *select* element wasn't working because the first *option* element had the `selected` attribute added.

**`selected` attribute broke the `required` attribute**

```
<label for="procedures_of_interest">Procedures Of Interest</label>
<select name="procedures_of_interest" id="procedures_of_interest" required multiple="multiple">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Select One or More</option>
  <option value="first">first</option>
  <option value="second">second</option>
  <option value="last">last</option>
</select>
```

By removing the the `selected` attribute from the *option* element, the `required` and `multiple` attributes both worked correctly on the *select* element:

```
<label for="procedures_of_interest">Procedures Of Interest</label>
<select name="procedures_of_interest" id="procedures_of_interest" required multiple="multiple">
  <option value="" disabled>Select One or More</option>
  <option value="first">first</option>
  <option value="second">second</option>
  <option value="last">last</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `required` part to `true`

So it'll be like `required="true"`, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

You are using required only which is HTML5 validation, may be its not work on all browser. Is you are looking for the proper validation i suggest to with jquery validation. 
[Validation Document](https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/#dependency-callback)